# Mdl Slider Value To Be Set Dynamicallty

Tags: angular

Hello I have a Simple mdl slider in my angular2 component where i want to set the value for the slider from my component dynamically.I have made a plunker demo here https://plnkr.co/edit/jXMff0gIfrBp1EervBZt?p=preview ...If i set the value for slider in html it renders correctly but if i assign a variable and control the slider value from component it doesnot work correctly.

```
<input class="mdl-slider mdl-js-slider" type="range"
  min="0" max="100" value="sliderData" tabindex="0">
```

this is my slider html where `sliderData` is my variable which holds the value.And i Have defined the `sliderData` to be `12`. Can somebody please tell me how to set the value for slider correctly

Comment: how is your code related to angular2-mdl?

Comment: Oh...I didnt think much when adding info

Answer (score 0):

See this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PTehIWrlRUSAWshWi07i?p=preview)

Here I have modified the followings:

Import followings in app.ts

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Import this in ngModule

```
FormsModule
```

In template add ngModel insted of value

```
 [(ngModel)]="sliderData"
```

Display the data in template as

```
{{sliderData}}
```